# Accessing vector items in GDB

Tags: c++, vector, gdb, stdvector

For example, I have such struct in a templated class:

```
struct Foo{
    int data;
    vector<Foo*> children;
}
```

And to print out the data value, I can simply do this: (let `bar` be a pointer to a `Foo`)

```
print bar->data
```

and this works fine. However I would like to also follow `children` to another `Foo`. I tried:

```
print bar->children[0]->data
```

but it doesn't work. How should I access the items in a vector and use it in `print`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24131961/283863), explicitly instantiating the vector fixes the problem.

For example,

```cpp
template class std::vector<double>;
```

Comment: Can you give an example showing how it solved your problem?

Comment: @user Sure, I’ve included the snippet from the linked answer.

Comment: How would I use it in `gdb`? I would run: `gdb) template class std::vector<double>;` and them `gdb) print bar->data` ?

Comment: IIRC I had to place it in the source code.

Answer (score 5):

With GDB 7.9 and g++ 4.9.2, it works quite well while printing `bar->children[0]->data`.

But, here is also an indirect method to access these elements:
`print (*(bar->children._M_impl._M_start)@bar->children.size())[0]->data`
where `VECTOR._M_impl._M_start` is the internal array of VECTOR and `POINTER@VECTOR.size()` is used for limiting the size of a pointer.

reference: [How do I print the elements of a C++ vector in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253099/how-do-i-print-the-elements-of-a-c-vector-in-gdb)

**Complement:**

There is also another not so elegant but more general way:

`print bar->children[0]`

and you might get something like this:

`(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Foo*> >::value_type &) @0x603118: 0x603090`

so you can access to it with the pointer given above:
`print ((Foo)*0x603090).data`

Comment: I'm getting an error saying `There is no member or method named _M_impl.` Probably that's because I'm using clang++ instead of g++.

Comment: So can I know your environment? Because accessing to internal array of vector depends closely on implementationof compilers...

Comment: Clang++, libc++, C++14 with no optimization.

Comment: What's the output of print bar->children[0]? If you can get the pointer of this element, then you can print data field with "print ((Foo)*ADDRESS).data"

Comment: When I try to do `bar->children[0]` it just says `Could not find operator[]`.

Comment: Oh I just found another [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24131961/283863) that made it worked by explicitly instantiating the vector. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
template <> Foo* &std::vector<Foo*>::operator[](size_type n) noexcept
{
    return this->begin()[n];
}
```

to use vector operator[], need the Template materialization