# How to tell which operand of logical operator was true/false?

Tags: c++, gdb, lldb

Suppose we have following C++ code:

```
auto found = std::lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), val);
return found != container.begin() && found != container.end();
```

How can I tell from a debugger which operand of `&&` operator was `false` -- a left one or a right one, or actually both?

I wish I could use `print`, but for some reason it fails:

```
(gdb) p found != container.end()
Cannot resolve function operator!= to any overloaded instance
```

Comment: Might it be that the debugger couldn't deduce the type of `found`? What happens if you just print `found`?

Comment: Step into the 1st call call put a breakpoint on the return, go to breakpoint, inspect the result that is going to be returned. Repeat if needed for 2nd call.

Comment: In your sample code you mention `container.end()` but in your sample GDB inspectino you mention `components.end()`.

Comment: @NathanPierson oops, sorry! I forgot to edit a variable name when asked this question, fixed it.

Comment: Related/dupe: [gdb Could not find operator[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130093/gdb-could-not-find-operator)

Comment: @JasonLiam it is maybe related, but certainly not a dupe.

Comment: @JasonLiam what if some of the operands contains a function call which has a side effect. We cannot call `print` with such function from gdb without messing up program's state, so the need of knowing operand's result is mandatory here. I require to reopen this question, because your "solution" is simply not applicable

Comment: Since the OP tagged lldb, it seems marginally worth pointing out that this expression runs successfully in the latest version of lldb w/o having to force the generation of template functions or other tricks.  At least that's true with `container` either a `vector<int>` or `set<int>`.  So it seems like gdb should be able to evaluate this one as well.

Comment: For some containers, `p found._M_current != container.end()._M_current` might work.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that this specific predicate doesn't make much sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply introducing two local `bool` variables, and then you can look at them as needed:

```
auto found = std::lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), val);
bool isBegin = (found == container.begin());
bool isEnd = (found == container.end());
return !(isBegin || isEnd);
```

Comment: Yeah, that would actually work, but debugging is already a very tedious procedure, and recompiling and restarting my binary over and over again makes it even more tedious, so I'm looking for way to avoid that.